# How to alter Boolean value from true to false and vice-versa

Tags: go, boolean, boolean-logic

I have a requirement in Go of altering the bool value and store it.
I am receiving value == true but I need to alter it and store the altered value.
I can think of only storing the alerted to a var and pass it in the next statement.

Eg psuedo code:

```
chnagevalue := false

if value == false {
     changevalue == true 
}
```

what's the best way to do it in Go? Is there any pre-defined way to do it?

Comment: This is the same as in C, C++, Java and C# to name a few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [logical NOT operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators) `!` to change true to false and vice versa:

```
changedValue := !value
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a short answer, written somewhere else :-)

Yours is almost good too:

```
changedValue := false

if !value {
     changedValue == true 
}
```

An if statement is always about something being true.
so in the above it reads : if a value equals false is true then {}.

of course your mind reads it the short way :
if a value equals false then {}.

the switch of course works the best:

```
changedValue := !changedValue
```

BTW: I would never use a fieldname like "changedValue" because...
every variable is a value of some kind, so there is no need of writing that.

"changed" should be enough.
or, when it is a boolean like this , even better:
"isChanged" or "hasChanged"